# How to receive SMTP mails in a python wsgi server on port 25

Tags: python, email, smtp, port, wsgi

how can i implement a server that receives and parse mails, like using the library

from smtpd import SMTPServer

but running forever under wsgi like http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_environment_dictionary

Comment: You can't. WSGI is a protocol designed specifically for HTTP requests, using it with SMTP is not possible.

Comment: Hi, please is there another way to do that? i need to just have a process running in background like i do with wsgi and apache.